# Removing Object via String C++ LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am writing a program that is essentially a library MIS system. You can add/remove books, max/min prices, etc. I am trying to create a `remove()` function to remove a particular book based on user input (using linked list). I am able to remove the Book title, but when I re-run the `output()` the code fails with an "Access Violation Reading Location". I know it is reading further into the list or not deleting something. It will not just remove the entire book as it did with my more simple `delete()`.

```
enter code here
void remove() {
    string remTitle;
    cout << "Enter book title to remove: " << endl;
    cin >> remTitle;

    Book *prev = head;
    //Find the first valid node
    Book *current = head->getNext();
    //While loop to run through the list 
    while (current != NULL) {
        //Stop loop if title matches
        if (current->getTitle() == remTitle) {
            break;
        }
        //Go to next list values 
        else {
            prev = current;
            current = current->getNext();
        }
    }
    if (current == NULL) {
        cout << "No value to delete";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Removing: " << current->getTitle() << endl;
        prev->getNext() == current->getNext();
        delete current; 
    }

}
```

Here is the output() :

```
enter code here
void output() {
    cout << "Book Title: " << title << endl;
    cout << "Author: " << author << endl; 
    cout << "Price: " << price << endl; 
    publishDate->output();
}
```

Mainly, my question is can this be fixed simply? Or is it much easier to create an index for each book (i.e. Book `ID = 1`) and use that for the remove?

Comment: `prev->getNext() == current->getNext();` I think you meant `=` there. What does `getNext()` return. Maybe you need a `prev->setNext(current->getNext());`?

Comment: Ah, you are my hero. prev->setNext(current->getNext())); worked perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` is the comparison operator, you need to use the assignment operator `=` here:

```
prev->getNext() == current->getNext();
```

like this:

```
prev->getNext() = current->getNext();
```

Also, as @JohnnyMopp suggested, what you need is `prev->setNext(current->getNext());`.